# How to use Tagged Type in Play routes file with Pathbindable

Tags: scala, playframework, phantom-types

For a service that handle a lot of ided entities, I'm trying to have some strong typing. To achieve this I'm using a technique based on phantom types/tagged type as it can be found in shapeless or scalaz. (I don't want to use AnyVal because I really don't want to pay the cost of boxing/unboxing)

I've done a minimal exemple which hit the following compile error :

`class type required but String with controllers.TestController.Tagged[controllers.MyId] found`

Here are the files :

- app/controllers/TestController.scala

```scala
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import controllers.TestController.TString
import play.api.mvc._

trait MyId

object TestController {

  trait Tagged[U]
  type TString[T] = String with Tagged[T]
  def TString[T](s: String) =  s.asInstanceOf[String with Tagged[T]]

  implicit def tStringPathBindable[T](implicit binder : PathBindable[String]) : PathBindable[TString[T]] =
    binder.transform(TString,identity)
}

@Singleton
class TestController @Inject() extends Controller {

  def index(id : TString[MyId]) = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok("")
  }

}
```

- conf/routes

  GET     /myroute/:id       controllers.TestController.index(id : TString[MyId])

The build.sbt

```
name := """play-tag"""

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

// Adds additional packages into conf/routes
play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys.routesImport ++=
  Seq(
    "controllers.MyId",
    "controllers.TestController._"
  )
```

- project/build.properties

  sbt.version=0.13.15
- project/plugins.sbt

  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.14")

Is there a way to fix this error ? if no what is the reason ? corollary question, what would be the best practice to achive what I'm trying to do ? For instance I'm not very happy with the fact that I'm exposing that the Id is composed of a string but I don't want to much boilerplate either as I have a lot of entities to deal with.

Comment: So I figure out that in the generated code appears a `classOf[TString[MyId]]`. TString being a structural type, it has no class... As is, there is no way to fix the error. The corollary question remains, what is the best practice to achieve relative type safety in such a context ?